# Custom Field Added In Comment Form Not Showing In Edit

Tags: comments, comment-form

This is my code in functions.php for adding the custom field in comment form

```
add_filter( 'comment_form_default_fields', 'add_phonenumber_field' );
function add_phonenumber_field($fields) {
    $fields['phonenumber'] = '<p class="comment-form-phonenumber"><label for="phonenumber">Phone Number <span class="required">*</span></label>' .
    '<input id="phone-number" name="phone-number" type="tel" pattern="[\+]\d{2}[\(]\d{3}[\)]\d{3}[\-]\d{4}" title="Phone Number (Format: +63(123)456-7980)" aria-required="true" required="required"/></p>';
    return $fields;
}
```

This is how comment form looks like now
[image]

But when I send the comment and click edit in the Dashboard under Comments tab, no phone number field is there.
[image]

How can I make it appear in when I edit the comment and display it in the approved comments on the front-end?
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 3):

Here's all of the code necessary to handle:

- displaying the custom comment form field on the front end (you already have that)
- displaying phone number within approved comments
- editing the phone numbber field on the back end within the edit comment page
- displaying the phone number within a custom column on the comment listing page

A good bit of this code was adapted from [this great tutorial](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/05/adding-custom-fields-in-wordpress-comment-form/).

### Display custom meta field on comment form on front end when submitting comment

```
// Display the phone number field on the front end.
add_filter( 'comment_form_default_fields', 'wpse248957_add_phonenumber_field' );
function wpse248957_add_phonenumber_field( $fields ) {
    $fields['phonenumber'] = 
        '<p class="comment-form-phonenumber">' .
            '<label for="phone-number">Phone Number <span class="required">*</span></label>' .
            '<input id="phone-number" name="phone-number" type="tel" ' . 
                'pattern="[\+]\d{2}[\(]\d{3}[\)]\d{3}[\-]\d{4}" ' . 
                'title="Phone Number (Format: +63(123)456-7980)" aria-required="true" required="required"/>' .
        '</p>';
    return $fields;
}
```

### Ensure phone number was specified, save comment meta data when comment is saved

```
// Add the filter to check whether the comment meta data has been filled
add_filter( 'preprocess_comment', 'wpse248957_verify_comment_meta_data' );
function verify_comment_meta_data( $commentdata ) {
  if ( ! isset( $_POST['phone-number'] ) ) {
        wp_die( __( 'Error: Please enter your phone number. Hit the Back button ' .
            'on your Web browser and resubmit your comment with a phone number.', 'text_domain' )
        );
    }

  return $commentdata;
}

// Save the comment meta data when saving the comment.
add_action( 'comment_post', 'wpse248957_save_comment_meta_data' );
function wpse248957_save_comment_meta_data( $comment_id ) {
  if ( ( isset( $_POST['phone-number'] ) ) && ( $_POST['phone-number'] != '') ) {
        $phone_number = wp_filter_nohtml_kses( $_POST['phone-number'] );
        add_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'phone-number', $phone_number );
    }
}
```

### Register and display meta box on comment edit screen

```
// Register meta box on comment edit screen
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes_comment', 'wpse248957_comment_edit_add_meta_box' );
function wpse248957_comment_edit_add_meta_box() {
    add_meta_box( 'title', __( 'Phone Number', 'text-domain' ), 'wpse248957_comment_meta_box', 'comment', 'normal', 'high' );
}

// Callback function for displaying the comment meta box.
function wpse248957_comment_meta_box( $comment ) {
    $phone_number = get_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID, 'phone-number', true );
    wp_nonce_field( 'wpse248957_comment_fields_update', 'wpse248957_comment_fields_update', false );
    ?>
    <p>
        <label for="phone-number"><?php _e( 'Phone', 'text-domain' ); ?></label>
        <input type="text" name="phone-number" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $phone_number ); ?>" class="widefat" />
    </p><?php
}
```

### Handle updating the comment meta data

```
// Update comment meta data from comment editing screen 
add_action( 'edit_comment', 'wpse248957_comment_edit_meta_fields' );
function wpse248957_comment_edit_meta_fields( $comment_id ) {
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['wpse248957_comment_fields_update'] ) || 
             ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['wpse248957_comment_fields_update'], 'wpse248957_comment_fields_update' )
    ) {
        return;
    }

  if ( ( isset( $_POST['phone-number'] ) ) && ( $_POST['phone-number'] != '' ) ) {
        $phone_number = wp_filter_nohtml_kses( $_POST['phone-number'] );
        update_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'phone-number', $phone_number );
  } else {
        delete_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'phone-number');
  }
}
```

### Handle custom column in comments listing

```
// Add phone number custom column to comments listing in admin
add_filter( 'manage_edit-comments_columns' , 'wpse248957_manage_comment_columns' );
function wpse248957_manage_comment_columns( $columns ) {
    return array_merge( $columns, 
        [ 'phone-number' => __( 'Phone Number', 'text_domain' ) ]
    );
}

// Display phone number custom column in comments listing in admin
add_action( 'manage_comments_custom_column' , 'wpse248957_manage_comments_columns', 10, 2 );
function wpse248957_manage_comments_columns( $column, $post_id ) {
    switch ( $column ) {
        case 'phone-number':
            $phone_number = get_comment_meta( $post_id, 'phone-number', true );
            echo esc_html( $phone_number );
            break;
    }
}
```

### Display comment meta on approved comments

The phone number can be displayed within approved comments by getting the phone number meta and echoing it within the callback function used by [`wp_list_comments()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments):

```
$phone_number = get_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID, 'phone-number', true );
echo esc_html( $phone_number );
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [`add_meta_box( $id, $title, $callback, $post_type, $context, $priority, $callback_args );`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) functionality of WordPress to add the comment extra field to the comments edit. Please [have a look here](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/05/adding-custom-fields-in-wordpress-comment-form/) you'll find a detail guide line here on ***"How to add extra fields on comments"***.