# How to add a title field in comments?

Tags: custom-field, comments, comment-form, comments-template

Just like WP posts have title and text, I want to have titles to my comments. Now how do I add it and show them above the comment texts like a title.

1. I need it to have a css name as well.
2. The title needs to be H3.

Answer (score 1):

1. Based on this [**tutorial**](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/05/adding-custom-fields-in-wordpress-comment-form/) , here is an [**answer to a similar question**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/248959/161501).
2. **[This](https://gist.github.com/chrisguitarguy/1233407)** may also help.

I hope this will help you start your journey by some tweaks and adjustment with code.

Comment: Well I like the github plugin. But the title is not required field. How do I make that required.

Comment: The `required` attribute specifies that an input field must be filled out before submitting the form. [TRY IT](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_required). **OR** Use the filter to check whether the title data has been filled. See example in [linked answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/248959/161501) for phone number.